# Can I cast a generic array of T that implements an interface, to this specific interface array?

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, interface, casting

I would like to do something like this : automatically convert array of T to some interface that T implements :

```
public static void GenericFunction<T>(T[,] genericArray) where T : ISomeInterface
{
    OtherFunction(genericArray);
}

public static void OtherFunction(ISomeInterface[,] interfaceArray)
{
    //stuff
}
```

This produces an error "cannot convert from 'T[*,*]' to 'ISomeInterface[*,*]' "
Is this possible to do without using Select or iterating whole array?

Comment: You're making your life hard with 2d arrays. Can you not use jagged arrays instead?

Comment: It doesn't really matter for me if this is an array or list in this case, the point is to be able to pass this container to other function without having to interate all objects. I'll take a look at jagged arrays too, though I'm using typical arrays mostly because I work on 2 by 2 grids all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The necessary conditions for an implicit conversion from an array type `S` with element type `SE` to another array type `T` with element type `TE` to exist are ([language spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#implicit-reference-conversions)):

> - `S` and `T` differ only in element type. In other words, `S` and `T` have the same number of dimensions.
> - Both `SE` and `TE` are reference_types.
> - An implicit reference conversion exists from `SE` to `TE`.

In your case, there is no guarantee that `T` is a reference type (second condition). One way to make your code work is therefore to constrain `T` to reference types:

```
public static void GenericFunction<T>(T[,] genericArray) where T : class, ISomeInterface
```

Comment: Amazing, this is exactly what I was missing, thanks a lot !